# right way to write stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.6

I have written one stored procedure in mysql database as follows :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test(
    IN Mode     VARCHAR(50),
    IN UserID   INT,
    ....
    ....  
)
BEGIN
    SET @sqlQuery = "";
    IF (Mode = 'Select') THEN
       //Select query
    ELSEIF (Mode = 'Update') THEN
       //update query
    ELSEIF (Mode = 'Delete') THEN
       //Delete query
    END
END
```

and as per my need I can call it like this

```
CALL sp_Test("Select", 1, ...)
OR
CALL sp_Test("Update", 1, ...)
OR
CALL sp_Test("Delete", 1, ...)
```

It is ok for performance? Or I should write individual stored procedures for each mode like

for SELECT

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test_Select(
    IN UserID   INT,
    ....
    ....  
)
BEGIN
    //Select query
END
```

for UPDATE

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Test_Update(
    IN UserID   INT,
    ....
    ....  
)
BEGIN
    //Select query
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no significant difference in the *performance* of these procedures (unless you're going to use them hundreds of times per second 24x7).

But there is a difference in *readability*. It's a significant difference. `test_DELETE(item)` is easier to understand than `test("delete", item)`. Keep in mind that you're writing code not just for the machine, but for the next person who will work on your project. Use your second alternative.

Comment: thanks @ollie-jones, welcome your suggestion, btw If my method is right, then how stored procedure is pre-compiled and execute faster?

Comment: Oracle precompiles stored procedures (from in the PL/SQL and Java languages). MySQL doesn't. It does have a cache.

Comment: my stored procedure is only cached right. So what about prepared statements in stored procedure?

Comment: In MySQL, prepared statements are implemented client-side. You can use your MySQL api (jdbc? PDO? whatever?) to prepare a call to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from performance restriction (if any at all); It's always recommended to have separate procedure defined for separate operations (`select`/`insert`/`update`/`delete`) because

> 1. It increases Redability.
> 2. Maintainability. separate procedure can be maintained well if at all any changes needed to be done in future.

Consider, about passing parameter for different operations. For `select` most probably you don't need to pass any parameter to the procedure but for `insert`, `update` and `delete` you will have to pass parameter. Will not be a mess for you to differentiate them within single procedure body?